# Locking down an apache server - Prevent '/' page from being visible to all

Tags: networking, server, apache2, security

I first installed Apache as part of a ZoneMinder setup.  I then added to the server with an ownCloud setup.  All this is only accessible to LAN or to WAN-through-ssh and that part works great.

I now wish to make my ownCloud service visible to WAN so family can take advantage of it; that requires it to be over regular http.  I have succeeded in this to some extent, but some requests to my server are replied with directory listings which I do not like at all.  For example, `http://mysite.cloudns.pro:1234/` returns the following:

```
Index of /

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[DIR]   html/   2015-06-24 11:20    -    
[DIR]   owncloud/   2015-06-04 09:43    -    
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at mysite.cloudns.pro Port 1234
```

I have already successfully locked down `/zm` from WAN by adding the following in `/etc/zm/apache.conf`:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168 localhost
```

How can I do the same for the default Apache page (`index.html`) and the root `/` pages?

Comment: You are looking for the "-Indexes"-Function: <Directory /var/www>... Options -Indexes... </Directory> (I'm sorry for the format. I am unable to find the layout options in the stackexchange APP)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.  Can you help: why doesn't the following take care of the `/html` directory and the Apache default page?: `sudo a2dissite 000-default`

Comment: While it may not answer the question, the following provides formidable results regarding the Apache home page: `sudo mv /var/www/html ~/html.orig`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing

The following can be done to have only the ownCloud service available to WAN.  They may be redundant, but combined they can only make for a safer system.

1) Assuming it is not needed, Apache's default home page can be moved to a storage place (and out of the active sites):

```
$ sudo mv /var/www/html/index.html ~/index.html.orig
```

2) To prevent ZoneMinder from being accessible from WAN, changing `/etc/zm/apache.conf` to contain the following will make the server respond with `Forbidden` unless the page is requested from within the LAN:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168 localhost
```

3a) To prevent `/` from showing a directory listing and show `Frobidden` instead, add the keyword `Indexes` in the '/' entry of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>
```

3b) And remove the keyword `Indexes` in all other `<Directory>` listings.

Finally, restart apache2:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```